# Wordpress CF7 substr first number in a number field

Tags: wordpress, plugins

In the plugin contact form 7 i wish the first number to be deleted. for example if the user types : 054222222 it will become: 542811833

I tryed doing this using

```
echo substr('$number_variable', 1);
```

Used this by ajusting the folowing code i found [here](http://blog.jainsiddharth21.com/2014/05/29/validate-number-field-in-contact-form-7/)
,this is my code:

```
    function is_number( $result, $tag ) {
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];

    if ($name == 'request-phone') {
    $stripped = preg_replace( '/D/', '', $_POST[$name] );
    $_POST[$name] = $stripped;
    if( strlen( $_POST[$name] ) != 10 ) { // Number string must equal this
    $result['valid'] = false;
    $result['reason'][$name] = $_POST[$name] = 'Enter 10 digit phone number.';
    }
    }
return substr('$result', 1);
    }

    add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'is_number', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'is_number', 10, 2 );
```

But this dosn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What about using JS/jQuery to achieve this?

Something like

```
// On form submit
$('div.wpcf7 > form').submit(function() {
    // Get the input element
    var numberInput = $(this).find('#input-id');

    // Get the input value
    var numberVal = numberInput.val();

    // Strip the first character from the input
    var newNum = numberVal.substring(1, numberVal.length);

    // Set the new number as the input value
    numberInput.val(newNum);
});
```